# mysql mark unique records between 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `_adagio_items` and `catlg_products` where columns `_adagio_items.ItemId` and `catlg_products.name` should contain the same values.

I want to find and mark records in `_adagio_items` that are not present in `catlg_products.name`.

So far I was able to create sql statement that finds such records:

```
SELECT ItemId
FROM _adagio_items , catlg_products
WHERE catlg_products.name <> _adagio_items.ItemId
```

Now I need to mark records in `_adagio_items` that i found. So I am trying to do this:

```
UPDATE _adagio_items SET _new_record = 1 
            WHERE ItemId IN (
                SELECT ItemId
                FROM _adagio_items , catlg_products
                WHERE catlg_products.name <> _adagio_items.ItemId
            )
```

and get an error:
"You can't specify target table '_adagio_items' for update in FROM clause "

Comment: also ideally i would like to avoid using "IN" statement since i have big number of records and i might eat up a lot processing power. is there any way to do this via JOIN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE _adagio_items 
LEFT JOIN catlg_products ON _adagio_items.ItemId = catlg_products.name
SET _adagio_items._new_record = 1 
WHERE catlg_products.name IS NULL
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for. thank u so much